# I have to output my data from DataBase and also copy all inputs from form to send them to myself, including real-time multiplying weight*pcs

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got some code where I have to **input my contact data** from client, and  **output data from MySQL database which creates new rows in table**

Also there's additional function which has to be inside the code - but I've no idea how to handle this problem. I have to count the amount of **element pieces x their weight** in real-time to show the client the **total weight the order is going to have.**

The problem is I don't know how to make the client see it whenever they change the value of **Pieces** in `<input>`.

Lastly, the data from the form and table has to be sent to employee via email.

**PHP Code:**

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="calculator" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" >
  </head>

    <body>
        <!-- including calc.php file which contains all variables -->
        <?php include 'calc.php'; ?>
        <!-- Printing the form -->
    <form method="post" action="sendform.php"><br>
    
     <center>
     <h1>TEST</h1>
        <input id="Name" type="text" placeholder="<?= $form['FIRMA']; ?>" class="form-contact" required><br>
         <input id="Adres" type="text" placeholder="<?= $form['ADRES']; ?>" class="form-contact" required><br>
          <input id="Email" type="email" placeholder="<?= $form['EMAIL']; ?>" class="form-contact" required><br>
           <input id="Country" type="text" placeholder="<?= $form['COUNTRY']; ?>" class="form-contact" value="" size="1" pattern="[0-9]{2}" maxlength="2" required>
            <input id="Phone" type="text" placeholder="<?= $form['PHONE']; ?>" class="form-contact" pattern="[0-9]{9}" maxlength="9" required>
            <br>
            
        <!-- Printing out the table -->
        
  <table class="table-responsive" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?= $form['PRODUCTS']; ?></th>
            <th><?= $form['CATALOG']; ?></th>
            <th><?= $form['DESC']; ?></th>
            <th><?= $form['WEIGHT']; ?></th>
            <th><?= $form['TWEIGHT']; ?></th>
        <br>
        </tr>

    </thead>
      <tbody>
      
      <?php
            # Database connection
                $dbhost = "localhost";
                $dbuser = "root";
                $dbpass = "1234";
                $dbname = "data";

                $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
                if ($connection->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
                }
                #echo "Connection successfull!";
                
                # Questions for Database
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `elements`';
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        //output data each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "<tr><td>".'<input class="pcs-input" min=0 maxlength="3" value=0 size="2px" style="background-color: white;" name="inputs[]">';
                            echo "</td><td>Nr. "  . $row["pcode"] . "</td><td> " . $row["fullname"]. "</td><td> " . $row["weight"] . "kg</td><td><div id='sumWeight'></div></td></tr>";
                            
                        }
                        } else {
                        echo "0 Results";
                    }

                mysqli_close($connection);
      ?>

      </tbody>
    </table>
        <!-- Counting all needed atributes -->
            <div id="totalWeight">totalWeight</div>
        <!-- Submit btn -->
        <br><button name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="form-button">Send</button>
        </center>
    </form>
        
    </body>
    
  </html>
```

### JavaScript Code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener(function()
    input.OnChange = calculateForm();
    function calculateForm() {
        var totalWeight = 0;
        $(".pcs-input").each(function () {
            var pcs = parseInt($(this).val());
            if (pcs < 0) {
                pcs = 0;
            } else {
                var weight = parseFloat($(this).data('weight'));
                var sumWeight = pcs * weight;
                totalWeight += sumWeight;
            }
        });
       document.write(totalWeight.toFixed(2) + ' kg');
      }
    )};
    </script>
```

### Updated

**Well it doesn't work again, no errors, just doesn't multiply**
I think the problem might be with transporting data from table/database into the variable, any solution?

```
 <?php
            # Database connection
                $dbhost = "localhost";
                $dbuser = "root";
                $dbpass = "1234";
                $dbname = "data";

                $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
                if ($connection->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
                }
                #echo "Connection successfull!";
                
                # Questions for Database
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `elements`';
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        //output data each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "<tr><td>"."<input type='number' class='pcs-input' id='inputs' data-weight=".$row["weight"];
                            echo "></input>";
                            # echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"].'';
                            echo "</td><td>Nr. "  . $row["pcode"] . "</td><td> " . $row["fullname"]. "</td><td> " . $row["weight"] . "kg</td><td><div id='sum-Weight2'></div></td></tr>";
                            
                        }
                      } else {
                        echo "0 Results";
                    }
        #Declaring JavaScript Code inside PHP
                mysqli_close($connection);
      ?>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function calculateForm() {
        var totalWeight = 0;
        $(".pcs-input").each(function () {
            var pcs = parseInt($(this).val());
            if (pcs < 0) {
                pcs = 0;
            } else {
                var weight = parseFloat($(this).data('weight'));
                var sumWeight = pcs * weight;
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.sum-weight2').html(sumWeight.toFixed(2) + ' kg');
                totalWeight += sumWeight;
            };
       $('.totalGewicht').html(totalWeight.toFixed(2) + ' kg');
      }
    )};
    </script>
        <!-- Counting all needed atributes -->
            <div id="totalWeight"></div>
        <!-- Submit btn -->
        <br><button name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="form-button">Send</button>
        </center>
    </form>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232410/discussion-on-question-by-szymon-zuraw-i-have-to-output-my-data-from-database-an).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall there are quite a few issues with your code, which can be summarised as problems with

- invalid HTML (e.g. duplicate IDs, incorrectly written `input` element, un-closed table rows, un-closed data attributes)
- over-complicated HTML
- typing or case errors (e.g. `W` instead of `w`)
- incorrect CSS selectors in the JavaScript
- lack of initial default data (e.g. if there are no numbers in any one of the input boxes, the calculation will fail because trying to add a blank value to another number results in `NaN` (Not a Number)
- calculation did not run when page loads, so data is missing until the user changes something (which is no use, if they want to see the current weight before changing any values)

This client-side demo demonstrates the HTML you need to get your PHP to produce, and the correct JavaScript / jQuery code in order to do the calculations and display the results:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".pcs-input").change(calculateForm); //set up the event handler

  function calculateForm() {
    var totalWeight = 0;
    
    $(".pcs-input").each(function() {
      var pcs = parseInt($(this).val());
      
      if (pcs < 0) {
        pcs = 0;
      } 
      else {
        var weight = parseFloat($(this).data('weight'));
        var sumWeight = pcs * weight;
        $(this).closest("tr").find('.sum-weight2').html(sumWeight.toFixed(2) + ' kg');
        totalWeight += sumWeight;
      };
      $('#totalWeight').html(totalWeight.toFixed(2) + ' kg');
    })
  };
  
  calculateForm(); //call it once when the page first loads too, to set up the initial data
});
```

```css
table
{
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

td
{
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='number' class='pcs-input' data-weight='3' value='1' /></td>
      <td>Nr. 14536</td>
      <td>Test 1</td>
      <td>3 kg</td>
      <td class='sum-weight2'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='number' class='pcs-input' data-weight='15' value='1' /></td>
      <td>Nr. 23431</td>
      <td>Test 2</td>
      <td>15 kg</td>
      <td class='sum-weight2'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='number' class='pcs-input' data-weight='4' value='1' /></td>
      <td>Nr. 33125</td>
      <td>Test 3</td>
      <td>4 kg</td>
      <td class='sum-weight2'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
Total Weight: <span id="totalWeight"></span>
```

Remember you need to move the focus from the textbox to another element (using mouse or tab key) before the "change" event will fire. (It will also run if you use the up/down buttons on the input box.)

So this means, as well as editing the JavaScript as I've shown, you need to alter the PHP so it outputs the HTML table rows with the structure and data I've demonstrated above.

This should work:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<tr><td>"."<input type='number' class='pcs-input' data-weight='".$row["weight"]."' value='1' /></td>";
  echo "<td>Nr. ".$row["pcode"]."</td><td>".$row["fullname"]."</td><td>".$row["weight"]."kg</td><td class='sum-weight2'></td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I've injected the code to the places where it should be but I've got the error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at index.php:42` which goes to `$(function() {`

Comment: That means you didn't include jQuery in your page

Comment: Yes, now it works, thank you so much, I've learned a lot because of you. 
Keep yourself safe

Answer (score 0):

## Resolution:

```
    <body>
        <!-- including calc.php file which contains all variables -->
        <?php include 'calc.php'; ?>
        <!-- Printing the form -->
    <form method="post" action="sendform.php"><br>
    
     <center>
        <input id="Name" type="text" placeholder="<?= $form['FIRMA']; ?>" class="form-contact" required><br>
         <input id="Adres" type="text" placeholder="<?= $form['ADRES']; ?>" class="form-contact" required><br>
          <input id="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-contact" required><br>
           <input id="Country" type="text" placeholder="49" class="form-contact" value="" size="1" pattern="[0-9]{2}" maxlength="2" required>
            <input id="Phone" type="text" placeholder="Tel" class="form-contact" pattern="[0-9]{9}" maxlength="9" required>
            <br>
            
        <!-- Printing out the table -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table class=".table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?= $form['PRODUCTS']; ?></th>
            <th><?= $form['CATALOG']; ?></th>
            <th><?= $form['DESC']; ?></th>
            <th><?= $form['WEIGHT']; ?></th>
            <th><?= $form['TWEIGHT']; ?></th>
        <br>
        </tr>

    </thead>
      <tbody>
      
      <?php
            # Database connection
                $dbhost = "localhost";
                $dbuser = "root";
                $dbpass = "1234";
                $dbname = "data";

                $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
                if ($connection->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
                }
                #echo "Connection successfull!";
                
                # Questions for Database
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `elements`';
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
                
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        //output data each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "<tr><td>"."<input type='number' class='pcs-input' data-weight='".$row["weight"]."' value='0' min='0' /></td>";
                            echo "<td>Nr. ".$row["pcode"]."</td><td>".$row["fullname"]."</td><td>".$row["weight"]."kg</td><td class='sum-weight2'></td></tr>";
                        }
                      } else {
                        echo "0 Results";
                    }
        #Declaring JavaScript Code inside PHP
                mysqli_close($connection);
      ?>

      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
  $(".pcs-input").change(calculateForm); //set up the event handler

  function calculateForm() {
    var totalWeight = 0;
    
    $(".pcs-input").each(function() {
      var pcs = parseInt($(this).val());
      
      if (pcs < 0) {
        pcs = 0;
      } 
      else {
        var weight = parseFloat($(this).data('weight'));
        var sumWeight = pcs * weight;
        $(this).closest("tr").find('.sum-weight2').html(sumWeight.toFixed(2) + ' kg');
        totalWeight += sumWeight;
      };
      $('#totalWeight').html(totalWeight.toFixed(2) + ' kg');
    })
  };
  
  calculateForm(); //call it once when the page first loads too, to set up the initial data
});
    </script>
        <!-- Counting all needed atributes -->
            Total Weight: <span id="totalWeight"></span>
        <!-- Submit btn -->
        <br><button name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="form-button">Send</button>
        </center>
    </form>
        
    </body>
```